# Call function from the controller which is belonging to another

Tags: titanium

I have two controllers 'keyboard' is belonging to 'index' controller

I know I can call function in keyboard.js from index.js.

But How can I call the function in index.js from keyboard.js??

in this cae I would like to call wantToCall() from fromhere() function

my index.js

```
var KeyboardCon = Alloy.createController('keyboard',{});
$.KeyboardView.add(KeyboardCon.getView());  
KeyboardCon.test() // I can call the function in keyboard.js from index.js

function wantToCall(){
    //
}
```

my indes.xml

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="GameWin" class="container">
    <View id="KeyboardView" />
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

my keyboard.js

```
function fromhere(){
   I want to call wanToCall from here.
}

exports.test = function (){
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that will do it for you.  You pass the $ into the keyboard controller to pass a reference so it can refer to the index controller in keyboard.  Sorry didn't have time to test it.

index.js

```
var KeyboardCon = Alloy.createController('keyboard',{index: $});
...    
exports.wantToCall = function(){
    //
}
```

keyboard.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
function fromhere(){
   args.index.wantToCall();  
}
```

Alternatively what I usually do:

index.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Index = $;
...
exports.wantToCall(){
        //
    }
```

keyboard.js

```
function fromhere(){
   Alloy.Globals.Index.wantToCall();  
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use exports, because I'll call wantToCall after many controllers have been loaded. BUT, I get the message: `[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,40482] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'wantToCall'`

Comment: I had to define like this: `exports.wantToCall = function (){//..}`

Comment: Sorry, I mean, it did not work. See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364151/titanium-alloy-calling-controller-function-from-another-controller/23364614?noredirect=1#23364614