# titanium alloy: calling controller function from another controller

Tags: titanium, controllers, titanium-alloy

Using SDK 3.2.0

I have a index controller that defines a function to set Android Menus.
I want to call that function from a variety of controllers that are nested loaded throughout the App.
Code:

```
//index.js
exports.setMenus = function(enabled) {
        var activity = $.index.getActivity();
        activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e){
           /...
        };
        activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu = function(e) {
           /...
        };
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}; 
Alloy.Globals.Index = $;
```

Then, way after, inside `home controller`, I try this:

```
function startRefresh() {
    //...
    Alloy.Globals.Index.setMenus(true); 
}
$.on('focus', startRefresh);
```

Got the following error message:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,40482] - In alloy/controllers/home.js:8,29
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,40482] - Message: Uncaught TypeError: Obje
ct #<Controller> has no method 'setMenus'
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,40482] - Source:         Alloy.Globals.Ind
ex.setMenus(true);
```

I have followed instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019972/call-function-from-the-controller-which-is-belonging-to-another). I want to use exports because the controllers calling setMenus are not children of index, they are deeper nested. I mean, I'm trying to avoid passing arguments between controllers.

Why setMenus is not been exported?

**WHAT WORKED:**

```
//index.js
exports.setMenus = function(enabled) {
        var activity = $.index.getActivity();
        //...
}; 
Alloy.Globals.setMenus = setMenus;
```

and

```
//home.js
function startRefresh() {
    //...
    Alloy.Globals.setMenus(true); 
}
$.on('focus', startRefresh);
```

Comment: Change exports.setMenus to $.setMenus.  That should make it accessible for future reference, but Swanand's answer is the better practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a function from a variety of controllers then you can write that function in `alloy.js`
for ex:

`Alloy.Globals.someGlobalFunction = function(){
    alert("Hello");
};`

and now you cal call the function anywhere like `Alloy.Globals.someGlobalFunction();`

Comment: Cannot do exactly that. Problem is Android Menus need to be set thru a activity (that a window is bound to) and the activity is acessible inside the controller. I ended up doing this inside the index controller: `Alloy.Globals.setMenus = setMenus;` and it works. You gave the hint, thanks.